# STM32 IAR no ITM trace output unless printf is included in the code

Tags: embedded, printf, stm32, cortex-m, iar

I have a small project that I added my own custom debug functions to so I could have some extra functionality.  They have been working great, and use the following method to send the data:

```
while(*bp)
  ITM_SendChar(*bp++);
```

I finally got around to switching over all the printf statements to use my own function and all the output just stopped.  A little playing around and I figured out as long as I have one single printf function compiled in, no matter where, ITM_SendChar works right out the gate.

It would seem there is some functionality compiled in when printf is used in the project that allows ITM_SendChar to work.

It is not a huge deal but I am fairly curious as to why this is.  Is there perhaps another way to initialize the ITM (Instrumentation Trace Macrocell) system without having to stick in a dummy printf?

Comment: After building your project, you're supposed to have a map file created. You can build the project without `printf`, rename the map file, rebuild it again with a "dummy" `printf` somewhere, and compare the current map file with the previous map file. In particular, search for the symbols `ITM_SendChar` and `printf`, and see if there are any differences around those areas. Your theory of "some functionality compiled in when `printf` is used" sounds weird, but if there is an "additional functionality" then you should be able to see it as part of the differences between the two files.

Comment: I also noticed that there are some subtle details controlling whether you see ITM output or not. I recommend to check out the lovely ITM howto on the atollic blog, which also points to external ITM settings in the trace adapter and such.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and I tried everything with correct configuration of the ITM Registers. But I couldn't figure it out.

My solution to not use memory intense printf, is to use `putchar`:

```
while(*bp)
  putchar(*bp++);
```

It even works, when I just have one putchar somewhere in the code which outputs one character and then output the other things with `ITM_SendChar()`

I assume the IAR automatically adds some configuration function as soon as the `putchar` function is included.